# How to write a regular expression to match 1Y but not 1YY in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that matches a string of digits followed by specific letters.

The valid letters are: `D, W, M, Y, LY, LM`
The valid digits are: `0 to 9`

I have the following regex but I need help with the following points:

- I don't want to match 1YY, or 1YM, or anything other than the char sets above
- I want to ignore case

Here is my code:

```
    this.isValid= function(inpt) {
        var re = "[0-9]+[Y|M|W|D|LY|LM]";
        if (inpt.match(re) === null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    };
```

I need the following results:

```
    isValid("1Y")  //  true
    isValid("1y")  //  true  (lowercase is valid)
    isValid("1YY") //  false (YY is not valid)
    isValid("1mm") //  false (mm is not valid)
    isValid("1LY") //  true
    isValid("Y1")  //  false (order is incorrect)
    isValid("1A")  //  false (A is not valid)
    isValid("1YA") //  false (A is not valid)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. What you have there is a string, not a regular expression, although `String.prototype.match` will run it through `new RegExp` for you. Best to write the regular expression with literal notation (`/expression/`).
2. `[Y|M|W|D|LY|LM]` is a character class saying "match Y, |, M, D, or L". For an *alternation*, use a group; since in your case you don't need to capture the result, a non-capturing group: `(?:Y|M|W|D|LY|LM)`
3. To do a case-insensitive match, use the `i` flag.
4. To say "match this but not followed by that" use a negative look-ahead: `(?!...)`. (But keep reading, I suspect you don't want to do that.)

So you could use:

```
var re = /[0-9]+(?:Y|M|W|D|LY|LM)(?![Y|M|W|D|LY|LM])/i;
```

Example with tests:

```js
this.isValid= function(inpt) {
    var re = /[0-9]+(?:Y|M|W|D|LY|LM)(?![Y|M|W|D|LY|LM])/i;
    if (inpt.match(re) === null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};

//I need the following results:
console.log(isValid("1Y")); // true
console.log(isValid("1y")); //true
console.log(isValid("1YY")); //false
console.log(isValid("1mm")); //false
console.log(isValid("1LY")); //true
console.log(isValid("Y1")); //false
```

***But***, if you want to match the *entire* string, no need for the negative look-ahead, just use anchors (`^` and `$`):

```
var re = /^[0-9]+(?:Y|M|W|D|LY|LM)$/i;
```

Example with tests:

```js
this.isValid= function(inpt) {
    var re = /^[0-9]+(?:Y|M|W|D|LY|LM)$/i;
    if (inpt.match(re) === null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};

//I need the following results:
console.log(isValid("1Y")); // true
console.log(isValid("1y")); //true
console.log(isValid("1YY")); //false
console.log(isValid("1mm")); //false
console.log(isValid("1LY")); //true
console.log(isValid("Y1")); //false
```

Comment: Thank you - matching the entire string was obviously what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the character class, which only specifies what characters should follow, with an *or* pattern, since you need to capture patterns such as `LY` and `LM`; And if you want to match full string, use anchors `^` and `$` to denote the beginning and end of the string:

```js
var sample = ["1Y",  // true
              "1y",  // true
              "1YY", // false
              "1mm", // false
              "1LY", // true
              "Y1"]  // false
              
console.log(
  sample.map(s => /^[0-9]+(Y|M|W|D|LY|LM)$/i.test(s))
)
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you did, and *why*.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [my example here](https://jsfiddle.net/0eepzzvx/).

```
function isValid (inpt) {
    var re = /^[0-9]+(Y|M|W|D|LY|LM)$/i;
    if (inpt.match(re) === null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The reason patterns like 1YY were matching were because 1Y is perfectly valid, even if it is followed by other characters which do not meet the pattern.  For this reason, a ^ and $ surround the regular expression to ensure that it matches precisely that.

If you want to combine several rules together, then you need to figure out a means to separate them that can be easily distinguished (otherwise you enter the troublesome discussion of where one rule ends and another begins).

Hope that helps!